# delphi idhttpserver search parameter

Tags: delphi, get, delphi-xe7

I want to search/compair parameters(GET) in idhttpserver in Delphi.
I do have a way to do it but I want to know if there is an easier way.
This is the method i use now:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
para:string;
paraa:tstringlist;
begin
  for para in arequestinfo.params do
  begin
    paraa := tstringlist.Create;
    paraa.StrictDelimiter := True;
    paraa.Delimiter := '=';
    paraa.DelimitedText := para;
    if paraa[0] = '...' then
    begin
      if paraa[1] = '...' then
      begin
        ...
      end;
    end;
    paraa.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am using delphi xe7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view it's wasting of resources to use a string list to parse only `param=value` pairs. Even worse, you were creating and destroying a string list instance for each iterated parameter and missed to use the `try..finally` by which you were taking the risk of memory leaks. I would do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Param: string;
  Parts: TArray<string>;
begin
  for Param in ARequestInfo.Params do
  begin
    Parts := Param.Split(['=']);
    // Parts[0] should now contain the parameter name
    // Parts[1] should now contain the parameter value
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No need to use `Split()` , `Params` already has its own properties for extracting the name and value of each item.

Comment: @Remy, d'oh! I'm having some troubles with string lists these days... jwz104, use the way suggested by Remy. Could you accept the other post, please ?

Comment: @jwz104, could you accept the other answer, please ?

Answer (score 2):

`Params` is a `TStrings`, which has indexed [`Names[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Names) and [`ValueFromIndex[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.ValueFromIndex) properties:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  name, value: string;
  I: index;
begin
  for i := 0 to ARequestInfo.Params.Count-1 do
  begin
    Name := ARequestInfo.Params.Names[i];
    Value := ARequestInfo.Params.ValueFromIndex[i];
    if Name = '...' then
    begin
      if Value = '...' then
      begin
        ...
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```